# Track a website being navigated and perform an action using Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new to Selenium web driver.
I am working on a simple concept. Say the user opens a website (say "facebook") in Chrome/Firefox/IE/Safari , is there a way to detect this using Selenium ?

What I want to do is, on detecting "facebook", after it is loaded, auto fill the user-name and password fields.

Comment: First you to initiate WebDriver with any one of browser. Depends on that initialization you code will execute on particular browser.

Comment: Whenever I am initializing a ChromeDriver (say) a new instance of chrome is opened. What if I want to use the already opened instance ?

Comment: Use test suit by passing param as a browser name.

Comment: You want to use already opened Chrome[default installation] or ChromeDriver[launched via selenium] instance.

Comment: If default is open, then the default one, else the ChromeDriver